# Program Crashing After Hitting the Submit Button

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, android-emulator

This has my instructor and I stumped.  After the user selects either the Rock button, Paper button, Scissors button, Lizard button, or Spock button and then selects the Submit button, the program crashes in the emulator and a message pops up saying that it "Unexpectedly Stopped Working."  What's even more strange is that there are no error messages in the console or logcat.  Also, when the user's choice and the computer's choice are the same, Ties does NOT increment, but the Losses does.  I'm not sure what exactly is going on.  I thought that maybe a fresh pair of eyes would help, since I am new to Android and I stumped my instructor.  Thank you.  Here is the code for GameFragment.java.  As you can see, I split it into multiple functions to make it easier to call things elsewhere, instead of re-writing code.

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class GameFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener
{
 //private static final String TAG = "RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock Activity";

 private int currentRound;
 private int yourWins = 0;
 private int compWins = 0;
 private int ties = 0;
 private int computerPick;
 private int playerPick;
 private int rock = 1;
 private int paper = 2;
 private int scissors = 3;
 private int lizard = 4;
 private int spock = 5;
 private Animation shake;
 private TextView roundTextView;
 private TextView playerWinsTextView;
 private TextView compWinsTextView;
 private TextView resultsTextView;
 private TextView tiesTextView;
 private Handler handler;
 private boolean didPlayerWin = false;
 private boolean isATie = false;

 private ImageButton rockImageButton;
 private ImageButton vaporizedRockImageButton;
 private ImageButton paperImageButton;
 private ImageButton scissorsImageButton;
 private ImageButton lizardImageButton;
 private ImageButton decapitatedLizardImageButton;
 private ImageButton spockImageButton;

 private Button rulesButton;
 private Button submitButton;
 private Button restartButton;


 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                            Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
     View view = 
             inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);

     shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.shake);
     shake.setRepeatCount(3);
     handler = new Handler();

     // References to the TextViews
     roundTextView = (TextView)
             view.findViewById(R.id.roundTextView);  
     playerWinsTextView = (TextView)
             view.findViewById(R.id.playerWinsTextView);
     compWinsTextView = (TextView)
             view.findViewById(R.id.compWinsTextView);
     resultsTextView = (TextView)
             view.findViewById(R.id.resultsTextView);
     tiesTextView = (TextView) 
             view.findViewById(R.id.tiesTextView);

     // References to the ImageButtons
     rockImageButton = (ImageButton)
             view.findViewById(R.id.rockImageButton);
     vaporizedRockImageButton = (ImageButton)
             view.findViewById(R.id.vaporizedRockImageButton);
     paperImageButton = (ImageButton)
             view.findViewById(R.id.paperImageButton);
     scissorsImageButton = (ImageButton)
             view.findViewById(R.id.scissorsImageButton);
     lizardImageButton = (ImageButton)
             view.findViewById(R.id.lizardImageButton);
     decapitatedLizardImageButton = (ImageButton)
             view.findViewById(R.id.decapitatedLizardImageButton);
     spockImageButton = (ImageButton)
             view.findViewById(R.id.spockImageButton);

     // References to the Buttons
     rulesButton = (Button)
             view.findViewById(R.id.rulesButton);
     submitButton = (Button)
             view.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
     restartButton = (Button)
             view.findViewById(R.id.restartButton);

     rulesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
     submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
     restartButton.setOnClickListener(this);

     rockImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
     vaporizedRockImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
     paperImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
     scissorsImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
     lizardImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
     decapitatedLizardImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
     spockImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);

     // Set the text for the TextViews
     currentRound = 1;

     roundTextView.setText(getResources().getString
             (R.string.round, currentRound));
     playerWinsTextView.setText(getResources().getString
             (R.string.player_wins, yourWins));
     compWinsTextView.setText(getResources().getString
             (R.string.comp_wins, compWins));
     tiesTextView.setText(getResources().getString
             (R.string.num_ties, ties));

     generateRandomNum();

     return view; 
 }  // End of onCreateView

 public void resetGame()
 {
     clearRounds();
     clearPlayerWinsAndCompWins();
     generateRandomNum();

 }

 public void clearPlayerWinsAndCompWins()
 {
     yourWins = 0;
     compWins = 0;
     ties     = 0;

     playerWinsTextView.setText(getResources().getString
             (R.string.player_wins, yourWins));
     compWinsTextView.setText(getResources().getString
             (R.string.comp_wins, compWins));
     tiesTextView.setText(getResources().getString
             (R.string.num_ties, ties));
 }

 public void clearRounds()
 {
     currentRound = 1;

     roundTextView.setText(getResources().getString
             (R.string.round, currentRound));
 }

 public void generateRandomNum()
 {
     final Random rand = new Random();
     computerPick = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
     computerPick++;
 }

 public void gameLogic()
 {
     isATie = false;
     didPlayerWin = false;

     if (playerPick == rock && computerPick == paper)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText(R.string.paper_beats_rock + R.string.you_lose);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
                 getResources().getColor(R.color.you_lose_color));
         didPlayerWin = false;
         theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == paper && computerPick == rock)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText(R.string.paper_beats_rock + R.string.you_won);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
                 getResources().getColor(R.color.you_win_color));
         didPlayerWin = true;
         theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == scissors && computerPick == paper)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
                (R.string.scissors_cuts_paper + R.string.you_won);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
                 getResources().getColor(R.color.you_win_color));
         didPlayerWin = true;
         theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == paper && computerPick == scissors)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
                (R.string.scissors_cuts_paper + R.string.you_lose);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
                 getResources().getColor(R.color.you_lose_color));
         didPlayerWin = false;
         theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == rock && computerPick == scissors)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.rock_crushes_scissors + R.string.you_won);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_win_color));
         didPlayerWin = true;
         theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == scissors && computerPick == rock)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.rock_crushes_scissors + R.string.you_lose);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_lose_color));
         didPlayerWin = false;
         theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == lizard && computerPick == spock)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.lizard_poisons_spock + R.string.you_won);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_win_color));
         didPlayerWin = true;
         theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == spock && computerPick == lizard)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.lizard_poisons_spock + R.string.you_lose);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_lose_color));
         didPlayerWin = false;
         theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == lizard && computerPick == paper)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.lizard_eats_paper + R.string.you_won);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_win_color));
         didPlayerWin = true;
         theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == paper && computerPick == lizard)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.lizard_eats_paper + R.string.you_lose);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_lose_color));
         didPlayerWin = false;
         theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == rock && computerPick == spock)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.spock_vaporizes_rock + R.string.you_lose);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_lose_color));
         vaporizedRockImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         didPlayerWin = false;
         theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == spock && computerPick == rock)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.spock_vaporizes_rock + R.string.you_won);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_win_color));
         didPlayerWin = true;
         vaporizedRockImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == paper && computerPick == spock)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.paper_disproves_spock + R.string.you_won);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_win_color));
         didPlayerWin = true;
         theHandler();
     }
     else if (playerPick == spock && computerPick == paper)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.paper_disproves_spock + R.string.you_lose);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_lose_color));
         didPlayerWin = false;
         theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == lizard && computerPick == rock)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.rock_crushes_lizard + R.string.you_lose);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_lose_color));
         didPlayerWin = false;
         theHandler();
     }
     else if (playerPick == rock && computerPick == lizard)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.rock_crushes_lizard + R.string.you_won);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_win_color));
         didPlayerWin = true;
         theHandler();
     }
     else if (playerPick == lizard && computerPick == scissors)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.scissors_decapitates_lizard + R.string.you_lose);
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_lose_color));
         decapitatedLizardImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         didPlayerWin = false;
         theHandler();
     }
     else if (playerPick == scissors && computerPick == lizard)
     {
        resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.scissors_decapitates_lizard + R.string.you_won);
        resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_win_color)); 
        decapitatedLizardImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        didPlayerWin = true;
        theHandler();
     }

     else if (playerPick == computerPick)
     {
         resultsTextView.setText
            (R.string.its_a_tie);
        resultsTextView.setTextColor(
             getResources().getColor(R.color.you_lose_color));
         isATie = true;
         didPlayerWin = false;
         theHandler();
     }
 }


public void onClick(View v) 
{
    //v = (ImageButton) v;
    if (v == rulesButton)
    {
        showRules();
    }
    if (v == restartButton)
    {
        resetGame();
    }
    if (v == submitButton)
    {
        gameLogic();
    }
    if (v == rockImageButton)
    {
        playerPick = rock;
    }
    if (v == paperImageButton)
    {
        playerPick = paper;
    }
    if (v == scissorsImageButton)
    {
        playerPick = scissors;
    }
    if (v == lizardImageButton)
    {
        playerPick = lizard;
    }
    if (v == spockImageButton)
    {
        playerPick = spock;
    }  

}



public void showRules()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder a1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Setting Dialog Title
    a1.setTitle("RULES");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    a1.setMessage("Here are the rules for Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock:\n\n" 
            + "\t-Paper beats Rock" + "\n\t-Rock beats Scissors" + 
            "\n\t-Scissors beats Paper" + "\n\t-Rock crushes Lizard" + 
            "\n\t-Lizard poisons Spock" + "\n\t-Spock smashes Scissors" + 
            "\n\t-Scissors decapitate Lizard" + "\n\t-Lizard eats Paper" 
            + "\n\t-Paper disproves Spock" + "\n\t-Spock vaporizes Rock" 
            + "\n\nIf there is a tie, the round will continue until a " + 
            "winner is found.");

    // Setting OK Button
    a1.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        //@Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
    // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed

            dialog.dismiss();                   
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    AlertDialog alertDialog = a1.create();
    a1.show();

}  


// Handler method for loading the next round
public void theHandler()
{
    handler.postDelayed(
        new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                loadNextRound();
            }

        }, 2000);
}

// loadNextRound method loads the next round and updates the textviews
// and image buttons (if needed).
public void loadNextRound()
{
    if (didPlayerWin == true)
    {
        resultsTextView.setText("");

        roundTextView.setText(getResources().getString
                (R.string.round, (currentRound + 1)));

        playerWinsTextView.setText(getResources().getString
                 (R.string.player_wins, (yourWins + 1)));
        didPlayerWin = false;

        generateRandomNum();
    }
    else if (didPlayerWin == false)
    {
        resultsTextView.setText("");

        roundTextView.setText(getResources().getString
                (R.string.round, (currentRound + 1)));

        compWinsTextView.setText(getResources().getString
                 (R.string.comp_wins, (compWins + 1)));
        didPlayerWin = false;

        generateRandomNum();
    }
    else if (isATie == true)
    {
        resultsTextView.setText("");

        tiesTextView.setText(getResources().getString
                (R.string.num_ties, (ties + 1)));
        isATie = false;

        generateRandomNum();
    }
    //generateRandomNum();
    vaporizedRockImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    decapitatedLizardImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

  } // End of loadNextRound method.
}
```

Sorry if this looks funny, I'm still getting used to putting code on this site.

Comment: can you post the exception you're getting ?

Comment: look for the exception in logcat

Comment: I don't understand.  I don't think I'm getting an exception.

Comment: OP has already said no error messages shown in logcat... read the post more carefully. However, that being said, why don't you put in a bunch of `log.i("LOG", "whereyourprogramis");` calls in your code, before each line? That way, when your program dies you can still trace logcat to see where it got up to. As it stands, this is a massive codedump. Please eliminate irrelevant code. MVCE would help a lot.

Comment: @InSeriousNeedOfAspirin : Just because you don't think there are any exceptions in the logcat doesn't mean there aren't any. An app doesn't suddenly throw up an "Unexpectedly Stopped Working" message without an unhandled exception having been thrown somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the code I believe that it is due to how you are setting the text in gameLogic(). 
change:

`resultsTextView.setText(R.string.paper_beats_rock + R.string.you_lose);`

to:

```
resultsTextView.setText(getString(R.string.paper_beats_rock) + getString(R.string.you_lose));
```

Comment: I did that and it works, however, now I'm getting something like, "Lizard poisons Spock.212121212121".

Comment: Oops!  Nevermind, I wrote something wrong.  Now it works right, however, the wins, losses, and ties are only incrementing the first time and then they stop incrementing.  Also, sometimes, it I hit a button and then hit submit, nothing happens.

Comment: move the increment of the win/lose/tie before showing it in the text. comWins++;  compWinsTextView.setText(getResources().getString
                 (R.string.comp_wins, compWins));

Comment: Okay, it's working, but whenever I get a tie it increments losses instead of Ties.  :(

Comment: Reorder your last two if blocks in the loadNextRound, your tie never gets hit because the way your block is set its either win/lose.

Comment: Okay, the Ties is working properly now.  I just don't understand why, now, the scissors button doesn't work until about 3 rounds or so later.  Thank you for being so patient and so helpful.  It's not your fault, but this program has been making me feel like throwing something.  XD

Comment: Check your game logic, I assume it is in there you missed a check as I count playPick of 4 for rock and paper but 3 for scissors

Comment: Yup, you were right, I was missing something.  I'm such a doofus!

Comment: we all make mistakes, keep at it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the text on your results TextView properly.

The problem is at lines such as this:

```
resultsTextView.setText(R.string.paper_beats_rock + R.string.you_lose);
```

`R.string.paper_beats_rock` is an integer. It refers to a string defined in your `strings.xml`, but is not the string itself.

If we assume that the ID of your `paper_beats_rock` string is 20 and the ID for `you_lose` is 36, then what you are really saying is that you want Android to look up the string associated with the ID of 56 (20 + 36).

Due to the way IDs are generated, there is a very good chance that no string with that ID exists, and your application will crash with a `ResourceNotFoundException`.

If you want to concatenate the strings, you should call [`getString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getString(int)) on those IDs first.

This exception *will* appear in your LogCat as well, so it sounds like you also aren't quite looking at your logcat correctly.